# How To Set dxn runtime to .net 4.6.1 with Rc1 - Final

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-4.6, .net-4.6.1

I've a new asp 5 MVC project wiht rc1- final. It is working. Then I change the framework from

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
```

to

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx461": { },
```

as a result I got the following exception

> The current runtime target framework is not compatible with project
>   [image]

I can also see that the current version is 4.5.1
Isn't currently .net4.6.1 supported?

Before the Rc-Final release I was at least able to use .net 4.6.0 
?

Is there a way to force the runtimeversion do 4.6.1 ?

Is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is currently not yet possible to use dnx461. I get the same error with that version. dnx46 and prior versions are working fine.

Comment: Is dnx461 available yet? If not, have you got any idea when it will be available?

Comment: They partially changed to the new dotnet target framework monikers: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98

Maybe it is possible now with the new one: net461 instead of net451. I have not tried it until yet, because the monikers don't work in all project types. Hopefully it is complete in RC2

Answer (score 2):

> Before the Rc-Final release I was at least able to use .net 4.6.0 ?

You can target to .net 4.6 now.

For that use:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  }
```

About target frameworks we can read [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md)

Comment: yes 46 work but not 461 (which has important bugfixes)